# Swift: a struct looks like an enum case, followed by (.)

Tags: swift, struct, enums

I was reading someone's else framework code, and I found one of the functions' parameter takes an input, the input is followed by (.), and when I checked the type of the input I found out that, it is a struct not an enum, which made me confused

Here is the function's screenshot with the input that looks like an enum case:

the input of the parameter is (.caption2)

[Function Parameter's Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GTEZ.png)

and here is how i found out that the parameter type is a struct not an enum
[Function parameter's Type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/du2E5.png)

any explanation why does the parameter look like an enum case?

thank you

Comment: Please show the core part of the code as text (not link nor image). Anyway, Swift can accept dot-leaded expression in a certain condition, even if it's a struct or a class.

Answer (score 2):

This dot syntax is not reserved for enums. It can be used for any member of the type in question.

For example, consider:

```
struct Foo {
    struct Bar {
        let value: Int
    }
}

extension Foo.Bar {
    static let baz: Foo.Bar = Foo.Bar(value: 42)
}

func qux(_ type: Foo.Bar) { 
    print(type.value)
}
```

Because `baz` is a static member of the `struct`, you can then you can do things like:

```
qux(Foo.Bar.baz)
```

Or, alternatively, because it’s expecting a `Foo.Bar` instance, simply:

```
qux(.baz)
```

---

Let’s consider a more practical example. You can, for example, define your own custom notification:

```
extension Notification.Name {
    static let myCustomNotification = Notification.Name("com.domain.app.myNotification")
}
```

Then, because the `name` parameter of the following method is expecting a `Notification.Name`, you can do things like:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .myCustomNotification, object: nil, queue: .main) { notification in
    print(notification)
}
```